# Problem in filling a form after opening a link

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and hence decided to create a script to:

1. Open a page
2. Fill a form on the page
3. Click the submit button
4. A new page will open
5. Fetch the data from this page and log in to the console.

But the remaining part of the script doesn't run after the page opens on line 1.

How can I accomplish this task?

```
    loginPage=open("abc.com"); //Open this page to fill a form there
    var mainPage;
    loginPage.onload=function(){ //once the page gets loaded fire this function
            document.getElementById("username").value="123456789"; //fill username with this value
            document.getElementById("password").value="abcdefghijk"; //fill password with this value
            mainPage=document.getElementsByClassName("loginbutton")[0].click(); //press the login button
        }
    mainPage.onload=function(){
            x=document.getElementsByClassName("tabletext");  //grab the table
            target=x[22]; //since the content is in the 22nd index, assign it to target
            console.log(target.textContent); //log the value of text inside target to console.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "abc.com" the same domain as the site that you're executing this script on? If it's not, it's simply not possible due to the fact that you're violating CORS / browser security measures. You cannot read the content from another domain using JS that doesn't explicitly allow all origins.